# Как понять, что перед тобой циклическая ссылка

Tags: python, python-3.x

требуется написать функцию, которая принимает произвольное количество любых аргументов(аргументами могут быть числа, списки и кортежи, содержащие внутри себя другие числа и кортежи, и т. д.. Функция должна вернуть произведение и сумму всех ненулевых элементов вложенных чисел.
с произведением и суммой, вроде бы, справился, но как быть, если вдруг попадется циклическая ссылка, подскажите пожалуйста способ понять, что передо мной именно она.

```py
def task_one(*args, a=0, b=1):
    args_id = id(args)
    total = a
    composition = b
    d = list(args)
    for i in d:
        if isinstance(i, (float, int)):
            if i != 0:
                total += i
                composition *= i
        else:
            c = task_one(*i, a=total, b=composition)
            total = c[0]
            composition = c[1]
    return [total, composition]
```

Пример вызова функции:

```py
c = [1, 2, [3, 4, (5, 6, 2, [1, 2, (5, 4, 0)])], 2, [3, 0]]
print(task_one(c))
```

Вывод

```
[40, 345600]
```

При встрече циклической ссылки должно вернуть:

```
 None
```

Пример передачи циклической ссылки:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 4]
a.append(b)
b.append(a)
print(task_one(a))
```

Вывод:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Владимир/PycharmProjects/untitled2/ArtezioHomework/Lesson3/fgdsf.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(task_one(a))
  File "C:/Users/Владимир/PycharmProjects/untitled2/ArtezioHomework/Lesson3/fgdsf.py", line 14, in task_one
    c = task_one(*i, a=total, b=composition)
  File "C:/Users/Владимир/PycharmProjects/untitled2/ArtezioHomework/Lesson3/fgdsf.py", line 14, in task_one
    c = task_one(*i, a=total, b=composition)
  File "C:/Users/Владимир/PycharmProjects/untitled2/ArtezioHomework/Lesson3/fgdsf.py", line 14, in task_one
    c = task_one(*i, a=total, b=composition)
  [Previous line repeated 994 more times]
  File "C:/Users/Владимир/PycharmProjects/untitled2/ArtezioHomework/Lesson3/fgdsf.py", line 9, in task_one
    if isinstance(i, (float, int)):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__
```

Comment: можете привести в вопросе пример данных с "циклической ссылкой"?

Comment: @MaxU добавил циклическую ссылку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Других вариантов не вижу, кроме как хранить set с id всех обработанных не-чисел в цепочке рекурсии и при обработке очередного не-числа проверять, нет ли его id в этом set-е. Можно передавать этот set аргументом в функцию task_one. Примерно так:

```
def task_one(*args, a=0, b=1, s=None):
    args_id = id(args)
    total = a
    composition = b
    d = list(args)
    for i in d:
        if isinstance(i, (float, int)):
            if i != 0:
                total += i
                composition *= i
        else:
            if s == None:
                s = set()
            if id(i) in s:
                continue
            s.add(id(i))
            c = task_one(*i, a=total, b=composition, s=s)
            total = c[0]
            composition = c[1]
    return [total, composition]
```

Кстати, промежуточные результаты можно не отправлять в функцию, а просто учитывать их на выходе функции в вычислениях:

```
def task_one(*args, s=None):
    args_id = id(args)
    total = 0
    composition = 1
    d = list(args)
    for i in d:
        if isinstance(i, (float, int)):
            if i != 0:
                total += i
                composition *= i
        else:
            if s == None:
                s = set()
            if id(i) in s:
                continue
            s.add(id(i))
            c = task_one(*i, s=s)
            total += c[0]
            composition *= c[1]
    return [total, composition]
```

Comment: присваивать, так как в функцию мы уже отправляем вычисленные не полностью сумму и произведение

Comment: @ВладимирПривезенов А, точно. Убрал )  В остальном то как - работает?

Comment: Дополнил ответ вариантом с вычислением и без передачи лишних параметров в функцию.

Comment: Да, все отлично, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы проверить, имеет ли объект циклическую ссылку, можно использовать встроенный модуль

```py
import pprint
```

и функцию

```
 pprint.isrecursive(obj)
```

Пример использования:

```py
FIRST_LIST = [1, 2, 3]
SECOND_LIST = [1, 2, 4]
THIRD_LIST = [1, 2, [3, 4, (5, 6, 2, [1, 2, (5, 4, 0)])], 2, [3, 0]]

FIRST_LIST.append(SECOND_LIST)
SECOND_LIST.append(THIRD_LIST)
THIRD_LIST.append(FIRST_LIST)

print(pprint.isrecursive(FIRST_LIST))
```

Вывод

```
True
```